# What to do when there is a change in a record in the Fact table?

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimension

What to do when there is a change in a record in the Fact table
For example, in the university, a class was held on Tuesdays. Two months ago, we set the record for that class on Tuesday, but now the class has changed to Friday. Now, what should we change if our chart is chosen two months ago? Show the class on Tuesday and show the class on Friday if the date is chosen today

Comment: It’s not clear, from the information you’ve supplied, why this would change any existing fact records. I’m guessing you create a fact record every time the class occurs - so one record per week - and the records include a reference to the date dimension. So previous records would reference dates that were Tuesdays and now fact records reference dates that are Fridays. What’s the problem with this? You probably need to provide a lot more information e.g. structure of the fact table, how you are using this data, etc

Comment: May be you are speking about the *slowly changing dimension* [SCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension). In the star model the classification in *facts* and *dimensions* is more a *convention* that a *strict distinction*.

Comment: The problem is that when we get a report of the classes held on weekdays, that class is counted twice, once on Tuesday and once on Friday.

Comment: I should also mention that we read our information in FullProcess and complete from the beginning every day, and Tuesday classes are included once with Friday.

Comment: We read our facts and records every day from the beginning, it happened that our old facts record was recorded with a new reference, with your guidance we came to the conclusion that every day we read yesterday's information only for the facts. Thank you. From the help you provided.Thanks NickW and Marmite Bomber